# Run multiple instances of nightwatch at browserstack

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js, browserstack

I integrated my nightwatch with browserstack. When I'm running one instance, it's working fine. But when 1st instance is working and someone is trying to run a second test in same time (on different browser or just from another branch of the project) 1st instance got error "Unable to connect to page", so probably 1st selenium server close connection. It's any way to do that? Ofc I have available 2 spaces for parallel tests in browserstack. 
Configs:
    nightwatch.conf.js

```
const chromedriver = require('chromedriver');

require('nightwatch-cucumber')({
    cucumberArgs: [
        '--require', './tests/step_definitions/hooks.js',
        '--require', './tests/step_definitions',
        '--format', 'json:reports/cucumber.json',
        '--format-options', '{"colorsEnabled":true}',
        './tests/features'
    ]
});

module.exports = {
    output_folder: 'reports',
    custom_assertions_path: 'tests/assertions',
    custom_commands_path: "./node_modules/nightwatch-commands/commands",
    live_output: true,
    disable_colors: false,
    test_settings: {
        default: {
            launch_url: 'http://pptm_nightwatch:3000',
            selenium_host: 'pptm_hub',
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                acceptSslCerts: true,
                loggingPrefs: {
                    'browser': 'ALL'
                }
            },
            selenium: {
                cli_args: {
                    'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriver.path
                }
            },
        },
        chrome: {
            desiredCapabilities: {
                browserName: 'chrome',
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                acceptSslCerts: true,
                loggingPrefs: {
                    'browser': 'ALL'
                }
            },
            selenium: {
                cli_args: {
                    'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriver.path
                }
            }
        },
    }
};
```

nightwatch.browserstack.conf.js

```
const defaultConfig = require('./nightwatch.conf');

const browserstackConfig = {
  selenium: {
    start_process: false,
    host: 'hub-cloud.browserstack.com',
    port: 80,
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        'browserstack.user': "bla",
        'browserstack.key': "bla",
        'browserstack.local': true,
      },
      globals: defaultConfig.test_settings.default.globals,
    },
    edge: {
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browser: 'edge',
      },
    },
    chrome: {
        desiredCapabilities: {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            javascriptEnabled: true,
            acceptSslCerts: true,
            loggingPrefs: {
                'browser': 'ALL'
            }
        },

    },
  },
};

const nightwatchConfig = Object.assign({}, defaultConfig, browserstackConfig);

Object.keys(nightwatchConfig.test_settings).forEach((key) => {
  const config = nightwatchConfig.test_settings[key];

  config.selenium_host = nightwatchConfig.selenium.host;
  config.selenium_port = nightwatchConfig.selenium.port;
  config.desiredCapabilities = Object.assign(
    {},
    nightwatchConfig.test_settings.default.desiredCapabilities,
    config.desiredCapabilities,
  );
});

module.exports = nightwatchConfig;
```

server.js:

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    express = require('express'),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var PORT = 3000;

function runServer(done) {
    var app = express();

    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.engine('html', cons.lodash);
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, './templates'));
    app.set('view engine', 'html');
    app.get('/page/:pageId', function(req, res){
      res.status(200).render(req.params.pageId, TEMPLATE_OPTIONS);
    });
    app.post('/form-endpoint', function (req, res) {
        res.status(200).send('<body>POST(' + JSON.stringify(req.body)+')</body>');
    });

    var server = app.listen(PORT, function () {
        done()
    });

    return server;
}
module.exports = runServer;

if (require.main === module) {
    runServer(function () {
        console.log("Starting server on port " + PORT + ". Please visit e.g. http://localhost:" + PORT + "/page/formSimple.html");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that the BrowserStackLocal binary is getting disconnected while your test is still under execution. It seems the issue is due to multiple spawns of BrowserStackLocal binary with same modifiers. Let me explain this with a sample scenario.

- Test Engineer 1 runs a test at 10:00 a.m (lets assume this test runs for 15 minutes): This creates a BrowserStackLocal connection on Test Engineer 1's machine and starts his test execution.
- Test Engineer 2 runs a test at 10:10 a.m: If this BrowserStackLocal connection uses the same key, it will disconnect the previous session already running at Test Engineer 1's machine and start the local connection on Test Engineer 2's machine. This may results in timeout or termination of test being run by Test Engineer 1 based on the error handling logic implemented.

When running tests sequentially, none of the tests will be impacted as the above scenario does not arise.

To avoid this, please ensure you are using **localIdentifer** parameter while starting BrowserStackLocal.

If you are using command line to start binary, please use the following command:

Mac:

```
./BrowserStackLocal --key ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier RandomString
```

Windows:

```
BrowserStackLocal.exe --key ACCESS_KEY --local-identifier RandomString
```

And in your test scripts, please add the following capability
**'browserstack.localIdentifier':'RandomString'**

This should make your desiredCapabilities block look like this:

```
 desiredCapabilities: {
    'browserstack.user': "bla",
    'browserstack.key': "bla",
    'browserstack.local': true,
    'browserstack.localIdentifier':'RandomString'
  }
```

​
This **RandomString** should be unique to each Test Engineer to ensure that their testing connection does not overlap or affect other Engineer's connection.